# Nodejs throwing 'Illegal Instruction' w/ SQLite3

Tags: node.js, linux, sqlite, cross-compiling

I'm struggling to figure out what to do, please help.  I have an embedded device (similar to a pi but not) running;

- arm linux (armv5tejl).
- node v0.10.44
- npm v2.15.0
- sqlite3 v3.8.3.1

I have a few problems and I've tried a slew of things, basically

```
npm install sqlite3
```

fails because the embedded board doesn't have make, I do have gcc 4.8.2. The reason I don't have make is because I cannot find the right .ipk package (using opkg). The versions of node and npm were all from opkg as well.

The closest version I could find of sqlite was node-v11-linux-arm and I think is the reason for the Illegal Instruction errors - instructions for a later version than my 5.

Any pointers on how to move forward?  Thanks!

Comment: Could be a bug in that and/or Node, so trying different versions of that package or trying to reproduce it on other physical hardware might be necessary.

Comment: I'd try with a current version of Node to see if that bug got fixed. The `v0.10` branch is pretty much obsolete with 6 being given long-term support.